# Closed electric field lines around an antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

Why do the field lines radiated from an antenna form closed loop after detachment?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Field lines terminate on electric charges, so  in the absence oif charges they do not terminate. More formally, in the absence of charges Gauss law  tells us that ${\rm div}\, {\bf E}=0$, which amounts to the same thing.

This tells us that the field lines have no end, but it does not tell us that they bite their iown tails and form closed loops. It is, however, is rather difficult generate non-closing lines when you are far from charges.  I can't think of rigorous way of provibg this though.

Comment: It's actually rather easy to generate non-closed field lines:  take pretty much any electric field with closed field lines and superimpose it with pretty much any other electric field (with or without closed field lines.)  I'm stuck at home with COVID right now but if I think of it when I'm back in the office I'll dig up a reference.